# How to get twilio to access content from a private S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, twilio

I'm storing TwiML files in a private S3 bucket that I would like the Voice Call API to access via a webhook ie

```
GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/test.xml
```

The Twilio debugger, of course, shows 403 since its a private bucket

```
11200 HTTP retrieval failure
```

Their [documentation](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183868-Which-IP-addresses-will-Twilio-s-requests-come-from-) says the IP changes so I can't just whitelist a bunch of IPS 
Is there some type of bucket policy I can apply to allow calls from the Twilio service?

```
    {
        "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from twilio",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "aws:Referer": "WHAT GOES HERE??????"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you make a policy based on a different header? There won't be a `Referer` but Twilio will send a `X-Twilio-Signature` header with each request.

Comment: yea this would be good idea, can't seem to find a way to check for headers specifaily yet. I found this post from 2014 saying its not possible, but not sure if it still applies

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=152013

Comment: Thing is, that's not really secure. You need to consider how secure you need this XML response to be. If you're ok that someone who knows the URL and to add the right header can accept it, then you likely don't need to obscure this file at all. If you really need it to be secure you should serve it from an application that can [verify the header really is from Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security#validating-requests) and not just serve it from S3.

Comment: Yea looks like will just have to have a lambda function verify the Twilio response, and have it serve the xml from S3

Comment: That sounds like it will work! 